# Logic not to run the Job on particular time frame

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to run certain job every 30 minutes. So far, I have added logic for the same. But, I have validation - It shouldn't run on Sunday from 00:00 to 10:00 CST.

I am stuck on the validation part. Can anyone help?

Below is the code -

```
package com.quartz;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class TriggerCron 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {

        Calendar calObj = Calendar.getInstance();


        if (calObj.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Job Details

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TriggerJob.class)
        .withIdentity("JobName", "group1").build();

        // Simple Trigger

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("TriggerName", "group1")
                .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInMinutes(30).repeatForever())
                .build();

    //Schedule it

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);    

        }

}
```

Comment: Is there anything you actually tried to address your problem?

Comment: I want to add the validation to skip running the job on Sunday from 00:00 to 10:00 CST.    

if (calObj.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
        {
            return;
        }

Answer (score 0):

The if condition should be in TriggerJob and not the main method which sets up the job.

Anyhow this is not the right way to set it up since now the scheduling conditions are in the job itself. I recommend using multiple cron triggers:

1. 0 0/30 * ? * MON-SAT, Runs every 30 minutes for monday to thursday
2. 0 0/30 10-23 ? * SUN, Runs 10 onwards on Sunday only. Not entirely sure if this is the right expression but try and tweak as needed.

The time zone can be set by:

```
withSchedule(cronSchedule(cronExpression).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"))
```